# Convert string to timestamps in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have the string which is formatted as below:

```
Tue Feb 11 12:28:36 +0000 2014
```

I try to convert this string to timestamps in R by using:

```
timeobj <- strptime(df[1], format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
```

where df[1] is in format of `Tue Feb 11 12:28:36 +0000 2014`

However, I got an error as below:

```
Error in strptime(df[1], format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT") : 
  input string is too long
```

How can I fix this?

```
dput(df[ 1:5, 1]) =

c("Tue Feb 11 12:47:26 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 12:55:09 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:22:29 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:24:31 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:34:00 +0000 2014")
```

Comment: I don't get an error, but it returns NA for me, although I think your format specification is correct.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: `strptime("Tue Feb 11 12:28:36 +0000 2014", format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")` Please provide reproducible example: `dput(df[ 1:5, 1]`

Comment: c("Tue Feb 11 12:47:26 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 12:55:09 +0000 2014", 
"Tue Feb 11 13:22:29 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:24:31 +0000 2014", 
"Tue Feb 11 13:34:00 +0000 2014")

Comment: Thanks @yuyu. Please could you include the `dput()` output in the question body, rather than a comment? It's an important part of the question, and comments are temporary

Comment: Captain Hat, I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that your *locale* is not fitting the abbreviated weekday and month name.

```
x <- c("Tue Feb 11 12:47:26 +0000 2014",
  "Tue Feb 11 12:55:09 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:22:29 +0000 2014",
  "Tue Feb 11 13:24:31 +0000 2014", "Tue Feb 11 13:34:00 +0000 2014")

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "de_AT.UTF-8")
strptime(x, format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA

Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
strptime(x, format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2014-02-11 12:47:26 GMT" "2014-02-11 12:55:09 GMT"
#[3] "2014-02-11 13:22:29 GMT" "2014-02-11 13:24:31 GMT"
#[5] "2014-02-11 13:34:00 GMT"
```

The manual of `strptime` says: *'%a' Abbreviated weekday name in the **current locale** on this platform.*

Also it looks like you are providing a data.frame with `df[1]` and not a vector which can probably provided with `df[,1]`.

Comment: Yes sorry. I still can not reproduce the error shown in the question. Can you update the question that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: its still the same error as before Error in strptime(df[1], format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT") : 
  input string is too long

Comment: But with the given data in the question I can not reproduce this error.

Comment: Do you mean you need all the data?

Comment: Maybe try to use `df[,1]` instead of `df[1]`.

Comment: Omg it finally works. Thank you so much

Comment: Fine that it works now!

Comment: wait a minute, but now the problem is that when I print again the dataset, it becomes None for all

Comment: maybe you need to store it? `df$timestamp <- strptime(df[,1], format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")`

Comment: Yea I did store it but the result is all None

Comment: Does the locale fit, as described in the answer?

Comment: Error in df[, 1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. This error raised instead

Comment: Now you don't have the data.frame in `df`. Now you try to subset the function `df`.

Comment: a = "Tue Feb 11 12:28:36 +0000 2014"
b = strptime(a, format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
when i print b, b is None

Comment: Have a look at `Sys.setlocale`. **It looks like that your locale is not fitting the abbreviated weekday and month name.**

Answer (score 0):

%T is enough for the time.
`timeobj <- strptime(df[1], format = "%a %b %e %T %z %Y", tz = "GMT")`